# Double Bounce Reflection Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Imagine a game of pool but with arbitrary walls. I am looking for a way to hit a ball such that it bounces off two walls and then hits the target. [Illustrated Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKnxU.png).  Solving for one bounce is quite easy,
[Given this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhLLM.png), where the two circles are the balls and the wall is the line, one can directly solve for a, b, c and use the fact (reflection):

$$\frac{a}{d} = \frac{b}{c - d}$$

to solve for d.

For the two bounce case there are too many unknowns.  One can solve AA' and BB' directly but everything else must be reduced to simply two unknowns.  Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: @CalvinLin ah thanks, fixed

Answer (score 0):

HINT

[image]

(Rectangular billiard board).

For consistency, the angle sign convention here is anticlockwise.

Construct a ray diagram. If angles of incidences are $i_1,i_2$, (irrespective of distances between the two points of incidence is $d$),

then angle between normals

$$ \delta= ( i_1+i_2 )$$

and the total deviation between first incidence ray and second reflected ray is

$$ 2(i_1 +i_2) = 2~\delta $$

In case of double reflection *at a right angle corner*

$$\delta = \pi/2, \quad 2\delta = \pi $$

so that means the ray or ball goes in an opposite sense, same vector.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Note that the angles between normals are only i1 + i2 when the walls form a triangle (i.e. two walls across from each other, with angle between normals of 180, do not fit this constraint).  However, even in cases where that constraint exists, I end up with 8 equations with 8 unknowns.  I am completely out of my depth in how to get this equation to solve for the first angle in terms of just knowns.

Comment: A consistent sign convention to be followed as shown.

Comment: Thanks for this, my next problem is, is there a clever way to reduce the number of unknowns?  As I see it, what you have shown is a needed equation constraint.  But as I reason there are 7 other equations leading to a massive system of equations.  The only 3 knowns I see are the distance from each point to the wall, and the angle between normal.  All the other walls of the triangles that one can form are all unknown.